# XML: remove child node with same name as parent

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, nodes, itunes

Is there a way to bypass one of the nodes when parsing? I'm trying to manipulate an XML file of an iTunes library, and each node either goes by the name dict or key. I am trying to remove all data between `<key>4508<key/>` and the `<dict/>` that is directly above `<key>4511<key/>`. I have tried using element tree but have only been able to remove all song data, rather than the data for one individual song. This is the portion of the doc I'm trying to edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Date</key><date>2021-01-15T13:28:47Z</date>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>1.1.2.28</string>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Music Folder</key><string>file:///Users/noahmcleod/Music/Music/Media.localized/</string>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>318349ECE9B5EB2D</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>4508</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>4508</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Winner's Circle</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Bear Hands</string>
            <key>Album Artist</key><string>Bear Hands</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>You'll Pay for This</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>Alternative</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>Apple Music AAC audio file</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>7546167</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>202506</integer>
            <key>Disc Number</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Disc Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Track Number</key><integer>10</integer>
            <key>Track Count</key><integer>12</integer>
            <key>Year</key><integer>2016</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2020-09-08T17:18:29Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2017-03-07T00:58:38Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>256</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>22</integer>
            <key>Play Date</key><integer>3680627875</integer>
            <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2020-08-19T00:37:55Z</date>
            <key>Skip Count</key><integer>6</integer>
            <key>Skip Date</key><date>2020-11-21T06:40:11Z</date>
            <key>Release Date</key><date>2016-04-15T07:00:00Z</date>
            <key>Normalization</key><integer>4768</integer>
            <key>Sort Album</key><string>You'll Pay for This</string>
            <key>Sort Artist</key><string>Bear Hands</string>
            <key>Sort Name</key><string>Winner's Circle</string>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>EC271B839E062485</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>Protected</key><true/>
            <key>Apple Music</key><true/>
            <key>Location</key><string>file:///Users/noahmcleod/Music/Music/Media.localized/Apple%20Music/Bear%20Hands/You'll%20Pay%20for%20This/10%20Winner's%20Circle.m4p</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>5</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>4511</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>4511</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>New Design</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>The Qemists</string>
```

And this is what I'm wanting to end up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Date</key><date>2021-01-15T13:28:47Z</date>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>1.1.2.28</string>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Music Folder</key><string>file:///Users/noahmcleod/Music/Music/Media.localized/</string>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>318349ECE9B5EB2D</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>4511</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>4511</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>New Design</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>The Qemists</string>
```

Comment: Please post Python code and XML as text, not as images.

Comment: The xml in your question is not well formed. Can you edit your question and post a much simpler, stripped down, well formed xml sample and the exact expected output?